# Is index.js in cordova project necessary?

Tags: cordova

Do I have to keep this file (www/js/index.js) or can I delete it and put my project files instead?

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

I used to work with Cocoon.io and there were no index.js file, i was handling deviceready event myself.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are properly binding the `deviceready` event, you can replace or delete the `index.js` entirely. Make sure you also update your JS references from `index.html` accordinygly.

If nothing works when you test the app, it means you have broken the `onDeviceReady` handler.

Comment: "As long as you are..., ...delete the `index.js` entirely", isn't index.js for the server? I don't quite understand...